# ThreadSanitizer (TSan) instrumentation using LLVM opt and TSan passes

Tags: llvm-ir, instrumentation, thread-sanitizer

My goal is to instrument my initial IR with proper calls to TSan runtime library functions using LLVM `opt` tool and TSan passes. In other words, I want to end up with similar TSan instrumentation as when using `clang -fsanitize=thread -S` but by directly using `opt` and TSan passes instead.

As far as I know, LLVM has two passes for TSan instrumentation: `tsan-module` (a module pass) and `tsan` (a function pass). Both passes are available by default in  `opt`, i.e. are included in `opt -print-passes` report.

I choose [tiny_race.c](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) as my sample programe, where the `main` thread and the thread it spawns (`Thread1`) form a data race while accessing a global variable `Global`.

Here are the two steps I take to instrument the code my way:

1. Generating the initial LLVM IR for tiny_race.c:

   clang -S -emit-llvm tiny_race.c -o tiny_race.ll
2. Using LLVM opt to instrument tiny_race.ll with the two TSan passes:

   opt -passes='tsan-module,tsan' tiny_race.ll -S -o myInstrumented.ll

The above pass pipeline executes fine but the resulting `myInstrumented.ll` **lacks some TSan instrumentations**. More specifically:

- `Thread1` (child thread) is left completely un-instrumented.
- `main` thread only has `@__tsan_func_entry` and `@__tsan_func_exit` instrumentations and its accesses to `Global` are not instrumented.

Could anyone please explain why my approach produces a partially-instrumented output? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

---

To better display the difference between the IR resulting from my approach and the expected one, bellow you can find definitions of `main` and `Thread1` in each of them.

Here is `myInstrumented.ll`:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local ptr @Thread1(ptr noundef %x) #0 {
entry:
  %x.addr = alloca ptr, align 8
  store ptr %x, ptr %x.addr, align 8
  store i32 42, ptr @Global, align 4
  %0 = load ptr, ptr %x.addr, align 8
  ret ptr %0
}


; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %0 = call ptr @llvm.returnaddress(i32 0)
  call void @__tsan_func_entry(ptr %0)      *****TSAN INSTRUMENTATION*****
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %t = alloca i64, align 8
  store i32 0, ptr %retval, align 4
  %call = call i32 @pthread_create(ptr noundef %t, ptr noundef null, ptr noundef @Thread1, ptr noundef null) #4
  store i32 43, ptr @Global, align 4
  %1 = load i64, ptr %t, align 8
  %call1 = call i32 @pthread_join(i64 noundef %1, ptr noundef null)
  %2 = load i32, ptr @Global, align 4
  call void @__tsan_func_exit()            *****TSAN INSTRUMENTATION*****
  ret i32 %2
}
```

And here is the resulting IR when using `clang -fsanitize=thread -S -emit-llvm tiny_race.c` which is my expected result:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone sanitize_thread uwtable
define dso_local ptr @Thread1(ptr noundef %x) #0 {
entry:
  %0 = call ptr @llvm.returnaddress(i32 0)
  call void @__tsan_func_entry(ptr %0)     *****TSAN INSTRUMENTATION*****
  %x.addr = alloca ptr, align 8
  store ptr %x, ptr %x.addr, align 8
  call void @__tsan_write4(ptr @Global)    *****TSAN INSTRUMENTATION*****
  store i32 42, ptr @Global, align 4
  %1 = load ptr, ptr %x.addr, align 8
  call void @__tsan_func_exit()            *****TSAN INSTRUMENTATION*****
  ret ptr %1
}


; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone sanitize_thread uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %0 = call ptr @llvm.returnaddress(i32 0)
  call void @__tsan_func_entry(ptr %0)      *****TSAN INSTRUMENTATION*****
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %t = alloca i64, align 8
  store i32 0, ptr %retval, align 4
  %call = call i32 @pthread_create(ptr noundef %t, ptr noundef null, ptr noundef @Thread1, ptr noundef null) #4
  call void @__tsan_write4(ptr @Global)     *****TSAN INSTRUMENTATION*****
  store i32 43, ptr @Global, align 4
  call void @__tsan_read8(ptr %t)           *****TSAN INSTRUMENTATION*****
  %1 = load i64, ptr %t, align 8
  %call1 = call i32 @pthread_join(i64 noundef %1, ptr noundef null)
  call void @__tsan_read4(ptr @Global)      *****TSAN INSTRUMENTATION*****
  %2 = load i32, ptr @Global, align 4
  call void @__tsan_func_exit()             *****TSAN INSTRUMENTATION*****
  ret i32 %2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function-level `ThreadSanitizerPass` checks ([ThreadSanitizer.cpp:548](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Transforms/Instrumentation/ThreadSanitizer.cpp#L548)) if the function you are operating on has the `SanitizeThread` attribute (before instrumenting loads and stores)

```
    // Instrument memory accesses only if we want to report bugs in the function.
    if (ClInstrumentMemoryAccesses && SanitizeFunction)                          
      for (const auto &II : AllLoadsAndStores) {                                 
        Res |= instrumentLoadOrStore(II, DL);                                    
      }
    }
```

I would suggest writing a custom pass that iterates over all functions and assigns the `Attribute::SanitizeThread` attribute to them before applying the `ThreadSanitizer` pass.